# Better way to extract rows with specific string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of more than 10,000 rows and 6 columns (one of the column is "Name"). I want to extract all rows with specific Name.

For example if I want to extract rows with two name I used this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv') 

df = df[df.Name.str.contains("name_1|name_3")]

df.to_csv("Name_list.csv")
```

But the problem is that I have hundreds of names for which I want to extract all the data and if I use the above code I have to write (copy/paste) all the names which is time consuming.

Is there a better way to achieve my objective?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the name csv

```
namelist = pd.read_csv('name.csv') 
df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv') 
df = df[df.Name.str.contains('|'.join(namelist['name'].tolist()))]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to continue using a regex `contains()` approach, then you may form an alternation from some input Python list, e.g.

```py
names = ['name_1', 'name_3']  # add more names here if desired
regex = r'(?:' + '|'.join(names) + r')'
df = df[df.Name.str.contains(regex)]
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, in this case also I have to prepare a list called names and I have more than 200 names.

Comment: Well the names have to be stored somewhere, I'm assuming.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Names are in a separate csv file. Basically I have two csv files, one is 10,000 rows and other one 200 rows (with unique Name).